# Why is $-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{z}{a})^n = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{a}{z})^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

Why is $\displaystyle-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{z}{a})^n = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{a}{z})^n$ ?

For context, I'm trying to derive the following series expansion:

> For a complex number function $f(z)$ and a real number $a$,
>   $$f(z) =\frac{a}{z-a}= \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{a}{z})^n $$ on the interval $|a|<|z|<\infty$.

What I have so far is:
On the interval $|a|<|z|<\infty$, it is true that $1 < \left|\dfrac{z}a\right|$. Thus, 
$$\frac{a}{z-a} = \bigl( \frac{a}{z-a} \bigr)\left( \frac{ 1/a}{ 1/a} \right) = -\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{a}} = -\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{z}a \right)^n$$

My work so far may have mistakes, but if I have not made an error, how do I finish the derivation?

Comment: Can both series converge at the same time? For example if $a/z = 2$ then is $-\sum \frac{1}{2^n} = \sum 2^n$ sensible?

Comment: You can't finish. Because if $|a|\le|z|$ then $\sum (z/a)^n$ is not a convergent series . And if $|a|\ge |z$| then $\sum (a/z)^n$ is not convergent.